# Как преобразовать символьные вычисления в число на python

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки, переменные, int

Я пробовал преобразовать строку  "-5/x" в целое число и число с плавающей точкой, но не получилось.
Кто может помочь?
Пример кода:

```
y = input("Y= ")
primer = ''
count = int(input("Colvo: "))
i = 0
first_spisok = []
end_spisok = []
while i != count:
    for j in range(1, len(y)):
        if y[j] == "x":
            first_spisok += y
            first_spisok[j] = str(i)
            for i in range(1, len(first_spisok)):
                primer += first_spisok[i]
            if float(primer) % 0.5 or float(primer) % 1:
                end_spisok.append(float(primer))
                i += 1

print(end_spisok)
```

Comment: У Вас же строка содержит не только число, а целое выражение. Тут вроде только парсить...

Comment: приведите пример кода, чтобы было понятно как вы задаёте х и как  преобразовываете

Comment: Какая у вас задача? что вы хотите найти?

Comment: Я хочу найти точки для графика гиперболы

Comment: https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/parsing.html

Comment: Уважаемый автор, заголовок сбивает с толку. "Преобразовать строку в число" - это `"42"` -> `42`, а не вот это вот все. Это символьные вычисления.

Comment: Спасибо, а можно это сделать без библиотек

Comment: `y` вводится в виде: `1, 2, 3, 4` или одно число?

Comment: К примеру "-5/2" или "3+4"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Вариант 1**. Если вам разрешено использовать внешние модули, есть отличный пакет для этих целей [SymPy](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/index.html), устанавливаем его один раз через командную строку `python -m pip install sympy`.

Далее получается такой код для разбора и вычисления значения произвольного математического выражения с подстановкой переменных, для примера в коде вычисляю выражение с несколькими переменными:

[Попробовать онлайн!](https://repl.it/@moytrage/StackOverflowRu1223638#main.py)

```
import sympy
from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import parse_expr
expr = parse_expr('-5/x + y + sqrt(z)')
x, y, z = sympy.symbols('x y z')
val = float(expr.evalf(subs = {x: 2, y: 0.1, z: 9}))
print(val)
```

Вывод:

```
0.6
```

Если не все переменные из выражения заданы в `subs = ...` то будет ошибка/исключение.

---

**Вариант 2**. Если не разрешено использовать внешних больших пакетов, то простейший вариант это использовать встроенный в Питон [eval()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval), в таких выражениях можно например даже функции [math](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html) модуля использовать:

[Попробовать онлайн!](https://tio.run/##FYsxDoMwEAR7v2I7bGJCQkRBkcdQENkSxuY4IZvPO0cxWo1Wkwq7uH1q/VEMCDM7@JAiMVq15ET4ounGPuOBIhw7sb5Mo7JFsbjkHixez7fFpM55FV9k9J0alchvrMVNrX8)

```
from math import *
expr = '-5/x + y + sqrt(z)'
x, y, z = 2, 0.1, 9
val = eval(expr)
print(val)
```

Вывод:

```
0.6
```

Дополнение. Использование `math` модуля не обязательно, т.е. строка `from math import *` не нужна, если в выражении нет математических функций типа `sqrt(x)` и если например мы хотим не использовать ни одного модуля. Если нужен и импортировать все имена из math в глобальное пространство имён запрещено (через `... import *` в коде выше), то можно использовать [такую технику](https://tio.run/##FYxNDsIgFIT3nGJ2BXzWv7hw4VkIamNJaEvpi4Eaz450MZlMvpkJmftpvJTihjBFxmC5F10KEXc0@@shYYdctcyR5aoakQiZsFZ8JhzbE@EmPtbX3FWT25Tw1Xo7ao15uScbQ9D67aeH9YtUPyVCdCPL2lel/AE).

**Внимание** - eval() можно использовать только если выражение пришло из надёжного источника, т.е. например вы ввели его, а не произвольный злоумышленник из интернета. Т.к. eval() может исполнить произвольный Python код, даже вредоносный.

Comment: Спасибо, вы очень помогли

Comment: @Дима Кстати, если вам ответ был полезен и верен, то не забудьте зачесть ответ или добавить голос. Зачесть ответ как верный можно слева вверху от ответа, там птичку поставить можно. А чтобы ещё голос добавить дополнительно, то в том же месте стрелку вверх нажать.

Answer (score 0):

Т.к. вы не указали в каком виде вы задаёте `x`, я использовал модуль `random`.

```
import random

y = input('Y = ') 
x = []
number_of_points = int(input('Num: ')) 

for i in range(number_of_points):
    x.append(random.randint(1, 20))

result = [(x[i], float('{:.2f}'.format(eval(y+'[i]')))) for i in range(number_of_points)]
print(result)
```

Comment: Код запутывает :) Зачем нужно было делать `eval(y+'[i]')`? Почему просто не сделать аналогичное -- `y[i]`